# How to capitalise text in Grommet's Heading component?

Tags: css, grommet

I am using `grommet` for React project & wondering how I can capitalise text in couple of `<Heading />` component.

Answer (score 0):

I used inline styling.

```
  <Heading style={{'textTransform': 'capitalize'}}>{product.name}</Heading>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to make Header `capitalize` and doing `Uppercase`.

In your answer you are doing this,

```
<Heading style={{'textTransform': 'uppercase'}}>{product.name}</Heading>
```

Suppose your `product.name` = `mobile`, then as per your answer you will get output as `MOBILE` all `uppercase` letters.

To make it `capitalize` use this

```
<Heading style={{'textTransform': 'capitalize'}}>{product.name}</Heading>
```

Now you will get your desired output `Mobile` which is a `capitalized` one.

For more detailt on `uppercase` and `capitalize` refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp).